# MBP (2016) to Thunderbolt Display with Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter and extension cable

Tags: macbook-pro, dock, thunderbolt

I have a MBP15 (2016) and connected it to my [Thunderbolt Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display) via the official [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter]. but the cable is too short for my needs right now. I tried 3 different Extension Cables ([1](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B088NDW5B3), [2](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07K21PWJJ/), [3](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B089NSP821/)) but none of them worked (no image on the screen). Is there a cable that works? If not possible is there a dock that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Any thunderbolt 3 or 2 dock will work. Be sure to read the friendly manual - not all cables that fit physically in a thunderbolt slot are thunderbolt cables and cables can be faulty.

I’ve only seen 10 foot 2 cables in copper. You’ll need optical to go further and they are pricey but very long range. Two feet is the longest 3 cable I’ve seen.

- [https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Certified-Thunderbolt-Black/dp/B01AKP8Z4C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AKP8Z4C)
- https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=24721
- https://www.owcdigital.com/products/thunderbolt-3-dock-14-port

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the first cable does not work for me because I would need one with a "female" end.
I also would prefer one cable because this would be a cheaper option.

Comment: There is no cheap option @xxx . You need a dock to get the female thunderbolt to function. I would have offered the inexpensive option for sure if any worked. You need the 3-2 adapter if you get a 2 dock.

Comment: I bought this exact doc and if i connect the monitor directly or indirectly (with original usb c adapter). It says "cannot use thunderbolt accessory"

Comment: I’ve seen that with cables or faulty hardware. Have you worked with OWC support to make sure everything they shipped is operational? @xxx for us it’s usually a cable issue or the Thunderbolt Display is now failing or failed :(

Comment: sorry it works now: i had to use the original adapter, because the display port does not support thunderbolt2 and the original apple charging cable does not support thunderbolt 3